# Number of Unique Groupings of Students Without Repeating Group Members

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I'm working on a problem related to grouping students for a series of activities. The problem is as follows:

> Suppose I have $m$ students, and I want to divide them into groups of size $n$ such that each group is made up of students who have not previously worked together in the same group. I'd like to do this for as many rounds as possible.

If we only consider a single round of grouping, the problem is fairly straightforward: with $m$ students, you can form $m/n$ groups of size $n$ (assuming $m$ is divisible by $n$). However, considering multiple rounds of grouping where students can't repeat group mates complicates the issue.

One approach I've considered is constructing a graph where each vertex represents a student, and edges are added as students work together. Then, the problem becomes finding cliques of size $n$ in this graph. However, I'm not aware of a simple formula or algorithm that can solve this problem for arbitrary $m$ and $n$.

For specific cases, like $m=18$ and $n=3$, a brute force approach could work. But, I'm interested in a more general solution or understanding the combinatorial properties of this problem.

Are there any theories, formulas, or algorithms in graph theory or combinatorics that could help to solve this problem?

Any input or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's a little more complicated even in the case of one round of grouping. Yes, there are $m/n$ groups, but there are more ways of forming the groups. For example, I could divide four students as 1-2 & 3-4 or 1-3 & 2-4 or 1-4 & 2-3, for a total of three ways of dividing 4 students into groups of size 2.

Comment: You can formulate this in terms of geometry: each student is a point, and each group is a line. The requirement that students not work together more than once is equivalent to the requirement that there is at most one line through any two points.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_golfer_problem